# Doctrine 2: Efficient way to query a many-to-many association

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have a many-to-many association between two tables (franchise and players), built with an additional table (franchise_players).
I have create the three entities:

```
class Franchise 
{
    ...
    /**
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NBA\Entity\FranchisePlayer", mappedBy="franchise")
     */
    private $franchiseplayers;
    ...
}

class Player
{
    /* some fields */
}

class FranchisePlayers 
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var \NBA\Entity\Player
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NBA\Entity\Player")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="playerId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
     private $player;

     /**
      * @var \NBA\Entity\Franchise
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NBA\Entity\Franchise")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
      *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="franchiseId", referencedColumnName="id")
      * })
      */
      private $franchise;
}
```

My goal is to get all the franchises with their related players.

The obvious solution is easy but not efficient:

```
Get all franchises
foreach $franchise
    $franchise->getFranchisePlayers()
    foreach $franquisePlayer
        $franquisePlayer->getPlayer()->getFullName();
```

Another solution is to get all franchises and then perform a left join to get the related players for every franchise:

```
Get all franchises
foreach $franchise
    public function getCurrentPlayers(Franchise $franchise) {   

    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('p'))
       ->from('NBA\Entity\Player', 'p')
       ->leftjoin('NBA\Entity\FranchisePlayer','f','WITH','f.player=p')
       ->where('f.franchise = ?1')
       ->orderBy('p.surname','ASC')
       ->setParameter(1,$franchise);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

In this way we reduce the number of queries.

My question is if I can achieve my goal with just one query like this:

```
public function getFranchisesWithPlayers() {
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('f'))
        ->from('NBA\Entity\Franchise', 'f')
        ->leftJoin('NBA\Entity\FranchisePlayer','fp','WITH','fp.franchise=f')
        ->leftJoin('NBA\Entity\Player','p','WITH','fp.player=p')
        ->orderBy('f.name')
        ->addOrderBy('p.surname');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();     
}
```

I thought that the franchisePlayers field of the Franchise entities (and also de Player entity of every FranchisePlayer) would be automatically loaded but it seems that this isn't true.

Is it possible to do it? Maybe Am I doing something wrong in the mappings of my entities?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Yesterday I was sure that the less queries best efficiency but now I'm doubting. Maybe the cost of hydratating the result of this complex query is bigger than the cost of hydratating every result of the queries of option 2 (query for the players of every franchise in different queries). What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows how to create queries.  Might be worth taking a look.  Something like:

```
$qb->select('franchise,franchisePlayer,player')
    ->from('NBA\Entity\Franchise', 'franchise')
    ->leftJoin('franchise.franchisePlayers','franchisePlayer')
    ->leftJoin('franchisePlayer.player','player')
    ->orderBy('franchise.name')
    ->addOrderBy('player.surname');
```

Comment: I have already checked your suggestion but this query return an array of different objects. The first element is a Franchise, but the second one is a FranchisePlayer, the third one a Player, and the fourth one a FranchisePlayer again.  That is, I have all the object that I wanted in just one query (fantastic!) but mixed in the same array.

Comment: Just for focusing the question: I would want to obtain an array of Franchise with the franchisePlayers field already loaded (for avoiding extra queries). And these franchisePlayers objects should have the player field also loaded.

Comment: Check again.  The query as shown will return a list of franchise objects.

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right.I was not building the query properly. 

Do you think it is more efficient to execute just one query or it's better to execute one query for every franchise for getting the related players?

Comment: For these sorts of queries, a single query is generally best when you know you need all the additional information.  It's when you have multiple ManyToMany relations that things might start to slow up.  But every case is going to be different.